# How to solve the mess information in gcc warning

Tags: c, gcc-warning, gentoo

I compiled my porject on a 64-bit linux(2.6.39-gentoo-r3),GCC version 4.6.3
but when I do compiling , the warnings contain some unreadable characters.Just like below:

```
warning: field precision specifier ?.*?.expects argument of type ?.nt?. but argument 6 has type ?.ong int?.[-Wformat]
warning: format ?.u?.expects argument of type ?.nsigned int?. but argument 7 has type ?.ize_t?.[-Wformat]
warning: ignoring return value of ?.ystem?. declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

Although I can guess the messed parts, they looks bad. So does anyone meet the same issue or know how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually gcc uses `ASCII` or `UTF-8` encoding for its output. Check your terminal to figure out which encoding it is actually configured for.

As a quick workaround, try running the gcc command in this fashion to see if you can see valid characters (it uses `ASCII` here):

```
LC_ALL=C LANG=C gcc ...
```

If that fixes the problem, your locale is either not configured correctly or at least not the one you'd like to.

To list all the locales supported on your system:

```
eselect locale list
```

Based on [this](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/guide-localization.xml) guide, you'd need to set `LC_ALL` and `LANG` variables in your .bashrc to configure your locale choosing one from the above list (I'm guessing en_US.UTF-8 in your case).

Comment: I have tried it , it didn't work well. My command is : $ LC_ALL=C LANG=C gcc -c -fPIC -g3 -Wall -Wno-unused  -D_DEBUG_LOGGING  -D_GNU_SOURCE -I.  -Itest test_main.c
test_main.c: In function ?.ain?.
test_main.c:34:20: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
test_main.c:51:5: warning: field precision should have type ?.nt?. but argument 2 has type ?.ong unsigned int?
test_main.c:51:5: warning: format ?..*s?.expects type ?.har *?. but argument 3 has type ?.nt?

Comment: BTW , my local content is :LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved finally. I find it's the issue of my XSHELL
By setting XSHELL go UTF8 ， it works ok. Thanks to all of you !